# How do I combine Multiple TIF files into a Single TIF file?

Tags: image-processing

I have a series of **TIF** files and would like to merge them into a **Single TIF** file

How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `tiffcp`

Usage: `tiffcp [options] input... output.tiff`

For instance:

`tiffcp *.tiff output.tiff`

And you will have a resulting multipage tiff

Then tiff2pdf (a wrapper for ghostscript)

Usage:  `tiff2pdf [options] input.tiff`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135405/how-to-merge-many-tif-files-to-single-tif-file

A multipage tiff needs a multipage viewer, like qfaxreader, but if you convert to pdf, resulting file can be more easily seen with pdf viewers

Comment: Multipage tifs can be viewed with evince.

Comment: This seems to works very well. It's quick and doesn't hog RAM.

Comment: Please precise that wou need to install libtiff-tools on ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

`convert` can transform multiple files into a multi-page one:

```
convert *.tif all-in-one.tif
```

Comment: This works only for a small number of files. Somehow convert seems to try loading all the files in RAM at one go. If you have more than a few pages, my 4Gb of RAM get used up soon and then the PC becomes very slow, unusable in fact.

Answer (score 2):

I'm resurrecting this old thread because my team ran into this issue in the last week.

Since we couldn't find any multi-platform tools (Windows and Linux) that could merge multiple TIFF files (including multi-page TIFFs) into a single multi-page TIFF file, we ended up coding a small tool by ourself using .NET Core 2 and C#. We called the project ***MergeTIFF*** and we released the whole source code on GitHub under GNU v3 license, so that everyone else can use it as well; we also released the binaries for Windows and Linux (32-bit and 64-bit).

For additional info and/or to download it take a look at the following resources that we published to better document the whole project:

- [MergeTIFF on GitHub](https://github.com/Darkseal/MergeTIFF)
- [Specifications, dependencies and other info](https://www.ryadel.com/en/mergetiff-asp-net-core-merge-tiff-tif-files-multi-page-open-source-free-download/)